# Cannot pass env variables to docker

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to run a docker image with env variables.

But it doesn't work for me either with env.list file or by command line.

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d appname -e FOO='foo'
```

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"-e\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

```
run -p 49160:8080 -d appname --env-file ./env.list
```

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"--env-file\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

It does run if I just go:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d appname
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to place your environment variables **before** the image's name. Try this:

```
docker run -e FOO='foo' -p 49160:8080 -d appname
```

Comment: that's some crappy arg parsing :(

Comment: same with --env-file before image's name

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation ... [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

To set a value for a single command, use RUN key=value command.

Answer (score 0):

try below.. for ex:

docker run ***--env*** LOG_DIR_PATH='/code/${LOG_DIR_PATH}'