# Cannot pass environment variable to docker container

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables

I'm trying to pass an environment variable to my docker container. My command:

```
docker run my_app -e MY_CONFIG='/path/to/.env'
```

gives:

```
Error: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH: OCI not found
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I couldn't find this issue within a similar context. Am I misunderstanding a key concept?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot pass env variables to docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077676/cannot-pass-env-variables-to-docker)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `docker` command is very particular about the ordering of options. Options must come before the image name, so

```
docker run -e MY_CONFIG='/path/to/.env' my_app
```

works while

```
docker run my_app -e MY_CONFIG='/path/to/.env'
```

is interpreted as you wanting to run a program called `-e` within the `my_app` image (c.f. `docker run my_app /bin/bash`).